# Want to add multiple font in Single fabric Text box, don't want to add new Text box

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I Want to add multiple font in Single fabric `TextBox`, don't want to add new `Textbox`.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Test', {
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 150,
    fontSize: 20
});
canvas.add(textbox).setActiveObject(textbox);
```

Please give me solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `styles` property of Textbox

```
var textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Test text', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 150,
  fontSize: 20,
  styles: {
    // first line of text i.e Test
    0: {
      //first letter of first line i.e T
      0: { fontFamily: 'Arial'},
      //second letter of first line i.e e
      1: { fontFamily: 'Impact'}
    },
  }
});
```

> Here `0` key of styles indicate first line of your text and `0` key
> inside `0` object of style indicate first letter.

Comment: Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I want to add multiple font family,is it possible?

Comment: yes you can add, use `fontFamily`  to set custom font family

Comment: @Satendra, is there any to update one word, say 'Test'?